# spark.python.worker.reuse not working as expected

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

given this code block

```python
def return_pid(_): yield os.getpid()
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
pids = set(spark.sparkContext.range(32).mapPartitions(return_pid).collect())
print(pids)
pids = set(spark.sparkContext.range(32).mapPartitions(return_pid).collect())
print(pids)
```

I was expecting that the same python process ids will be printed twice. instead, completely different Python process ids are being printed.

`spark.python.worker.reuse` is true but default. but this unexpected behaviors still occurs if `spark.python.worker.reuse=true` explicitly.

Comment: I am not sure to understand. What is `spark.python.worker.reuse` supposed to do for you ?

Comment: As per spark documentation "If yes, it will use a fixed number of Python workers, does not need to fork() a Python process for every task....".

I am expecting that the python processes that were created in the first mapPartitions call are reused in the second mapPartitions call. But they are not.

Comment: I think this creates a process pool and you will see pid's of the process within the process pool, can you tell me the number of different PID values that you have noticed with this code? Also can you check for the number of different PIDS with numSlices = 1, https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#range-long-long-long-int- ?